# While piping a command's output to other command, what if the other command exits?

Tags: bash, netcat

`nc -q -1 -lk -p 8080 < pipe | nc example.com 8080 > pipe`

This is the command I'm working on. It mostly works fine, but sometimes connection to example.com is reset due to lower signal etc. and it stops working. How could I make it reconnect ? I did not see any option about reconnecting on error, but I believe this is possible to achieve with bash. Am I wrong ?

Comment: Your command looks broken. Since `pipe` is used for both `< pipe` and `> pipe`, it will be truncated before any data is read from it.

Comment: it works as I expected. how could it be broken ? pipe is a fifo